# How can I add raw data body to an axios request?

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, post, axios

I am trying to communicate with an API from my React application using Axios. I managed to get the GET request working, but now I need a POST one.

I need the body to be raw text, as I will write an MDX query in it. Here is the part where I make the request:

```
axios.post(baseUrl + 'applications/' + appName + '/dataexport/plantypes' + plan,
    {
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'Content-Type' : 'text/plain' }
    }).then((response) => {
      this.setState({data:response.data});
      console.log(this.state.data);
    });
```

Here I added the content type part. But how can I add the body part?

Thank you.

Edit:

Here is a screenshot of the working Postman request
[image: Postman working request]

Answer (score 112, accepted):

How about using direct `axios` API?

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: baseUrl + 'applications/' + appName + '/dataexport/plantypes' + plan,
  headers: {}, 
  data: {
    foo: 'bar', // This is the body part
  }
});
```

Source: [axios api](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api)

Comment: won't this mean that the data part is sent as JSON?

Comment: How can we get the data: from a react form? Ex: user provides input and then we can use the inputted data to generate the json body

Comment: @KarimTaha do we need anything else than `json` as sending format to the server?

Comment: This is not acceptable answer.

@KarimTaha asked about how to set the proper configuration to send raw data like postman request. 

This is just a code snipper on how the axios request works...

Answer (score 74):

You can use postman to generate code. Look at this image. Follow step1 and step 2.

[image]

If your endpoint just accepts data that have been sent with Body (in postman), You should send FormData.

```
var formdata = new FormData();
//add three variable to form
formdata.append("imdbid", "1234");
formdata.append("token", "d48a3c54948b4c4edd9207151ff1c7a3");
formdata.append("rate", "4");
      
let res = await axios.post("/api/save_rate", formdata);
```

Comment: I was coming to this post to help with an answer, and i just learned something new.. i never noticed or even clicked the code snippet button, and i've been using postman for more than i can remember.. +1

Comment: The best solution, works for every situation, thank you :pray:

Comment: Never knew postman could generate code. This was a savior for me. Thanks a ton

Comment: This is not what the question asks... raw body, not form data.

Answer (score 31):

You can use the below for passing the raw text.

```
axios.post(
        baseUrl + 'applications/' + appName + '/dataexport/plantypes' + plan, 
        body, 
        {
            headers: { 
                'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'Content-Type' : 'text/plain' 
            }
        }
).then(response => {
    this.setState({data:response.data});
    console.log(this.state.data);
});
```

Just have your raw text within `body` or pass it directly within quotes as `'raw text to be sent'` in place of `body`.

The signature of the axios post is `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`, so the `data` is where you pass your request body.

Comment: I don't know why but this is not working. Can you take a look at the screenshot I added? Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @KarimTaha Have you tried adding the whole text in place of `body`?

Comment: This is how you perform a curl -d 'some data to send' without a form field name in axios

Answer (score 12):

The key is to use `"Content-Type": "text/plain"` as mentioned by @MadhuBhat.

```
axios.post(path, code, { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } }).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

A thing to note if you use `.NET` is that a raw string to a controller will return `415 Unsupported Media Type`. To get around this you need to encapsulate the raw string in hyphens like this and send it as `"Content-Type": "application/json"`:

```
axios.post(path, "\"" + code + "\"", { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

C# Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Post([FromBody] string code)
{
    return Ok(code);
}
```

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/14/accepting-raw-request-body-content-in-aspnet-core-api-controllers

You can also make a POST with query params if that helps:

```
.post(`/mails/users/sendVerificationMail`, null, { params: {
  mail,
  firstname
}})
.then(response => response.status)
.catch(err => console.warn(err));
```

This will POST an empty body with the two query params:

> POST
> http://localhost:8000/api/mails/users/sendVerificationMail?mail=lol%40lol.com&firstname=myFirstName

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53501339/3850405

Comment: `"Content-Type": "text/plain"` tip you had was what I needed

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution:

```
axios({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://URL.com/api/services/fetchQuizList",
  headers: {
    "x-access-key": data,
    "x-access-token": token,
  },
  data: {
    quiz_name: quizname,
  },
})
.then(res => {
  console.log("res", res.data.message);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log("error in request", err);
});
```

This should help

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the params like so

```
await axios.post(URL, {
  key:value //Second param will be your body
},
{
headers: {
  Authorization: ``,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

this makes it easier to test/mock in Jest as well

Comment: -1 What in your answer is different to that of @Uddesh_jain (except for the `Authorization` header which does not count, as it is already in the question)?

Answer (score 4):

I got same problem. So I looked into the axios document.
I found it. you can do it like this. this is easiest way. and super simple.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('param1', 'value1');
params.append('param2', 'value2');
axios.post('/foo', params);
```

You can use .then,.catch.

Answer (score 3):

For sending form data in the body, you can just format the data in url params like this `'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=12345&client_secret=678910'` and attached it to data in the config for axios.

```
axios.request({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/',
    data: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=12345&client_secret=678910',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found that would work is the transformRequest property which allows you to override the extra data prep axios does before sending off the request.

```
    axios.request({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://foo.bar/',
        data: {},
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        transformRequest: [(data, header) => {
            data = 'grant_type=client_credentials'
            return data
        }]
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the transformRequest option. I am testing an API and wanted to deliberately send broken JSON data to the server. Your answer brought me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine for me when trying to send authentication credential in body in raw json format.

```
let credentials = {
  username: "your-username",
  password: "your-password",
};
axios
.get(url, { data: credentials })
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Used in **React js**

```
let url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/validuser`;

   let body = JSON.stringify({
     loginid: "admin",
     password: "admin",
  });

var authOptions = {
  method: "post",
  url: url,
  data: body,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  json: true,
};

axios(authOptions)
  .then((resp) => {
    console.log("response :- ",resp);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    alert(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios({
  method: 'post',     //put
  url: url,
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer'+token}, 
  data: {
     firstName: 'Keshav', // This is the body part
     lastName: 'Gera'
  }
});
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: Data part is sent as JSON here and not a simple string

Answer (score 0):

There many methods to send raw data with a `post` request. I personally like this one.

```
    const url = "your url"
    const data = {key: value}
    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    axios.post(url, data, headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

 let url='<your domain.extension>';
 let data= JSON.stringify('mydata');
 axios
 .get(url, { data })
 .then((res) => {
     console.log(res.data);
  })
```

For me this solution works, i.e. `JSON.stringify(your data)` , just convert your raw data using `JSON.stringify` method.

I hope this works.