# How to post query parameters with Axios?

Tags: javascript, mysql, post, axios

I am trying to post on an API with some query params.
This is working on PostMan / Insomnia when I am trying to by passing mail and firstname as query parameters :

```
 http://localhost:8000/api/mails/users/sendVerificationMail?mail=lol%40lol.com&firstname=myFirstName
```

However, when I am trying to do it with my react native app, I got a 400 error (Invalid Query Parameters).

This is the post method :

```
.post(`/mails/users/sendVerificationMail`, {
  mail,
  firstname
})
.then(response => response.status)
.catch(err => console.warn(err));
```

(my mail and firstname are console.logged as follow: `lol@lol.com` and `myFirstName`).

So I don't know how to pass Query Parameters with Axios in my request (because right now, it's passing `data: { mail: "lol@lol.com", firstname: "myFirstName" }`.

Answer (score 398, accepted):

axios signature for post is `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`. So you want to send params object within the third argument:

```
.post(`/mails/users/sendVerificationMail`, null, { params: {
  mail,
  firstname
}})
.then(response => response.status)
.catch(err => console.warn(err));
```

This will POST an empty body with the two query params:

> POST
>   http://localhost:8000/api/mails/users/sendVerificationMail?mail=lol%40lol.com&firstname=myFirstName

Comment: how can i send request with params and body with axios?

Comment: @khodekazemi  .post(`/mails/users/sendVerificationMail`, body, { params: {
  mail,
  firstname
}})
.then(response => response.status)
.catch(err => console.warn(err));

Comment: This doesn't support sending objects, such as a file.

Comment: @Thomas why do you say that and why is that relevant to the question?

Answer (score 34):

As of 2021 insted of null i had to add {} in order to make it work!

```
axios.post(
        url,
        {},
        {
          params: {
            key,
            checksum
          }
        }
      )
      .then(response => {
        return success(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return fail(error);
      });
```

Comment: Year makes no sense. For `axios` version `0.27.2`, `null` or `undefined` works as the second parameter. `axios.post(url, null, { params: { ... } })`

Answer (score 12):

In my case, the API responded with a CORS error. I instead formatted the query parameters into query string. It successfully posted data and also avoided the CORS issue.

```
        var data = {};

        const params = new URLSearchParams({
          contact: this.ContactPerson,
          phoneNumber: this.PhoneNumber,
          email: this.Email
        }).toString();

        const url =
          "https://test.com/api/UpdateProfile?" +
          params;

        axios
          .post(url, data, {
            headers: {
              aaid: this.ID,
              token: this.Token
            }
          })
          .then(res => {
            this.Info = JSON.parse(res.data);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use params and body together in a request with axios

```
  sendAllData (data) {
   return axios
        .post(API_URL + "receiveData", JSON.stringify(data), {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
          params: { mail: xyx@example.col }, //Add mail as a param
        })
        .then((response) => console.log("repsonse", response.status)); 
  }
```