# How to pass multiple parameters as an object in url using react

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass multiple parameters to my api (Koa) via URL (from ReactJS using Axios) to post data to my db. This code is working, but I am wondering if there is an easier way to pass data instead of typing out each value to insert into the database?

I am adding an advising time to my db as such:

In ReactJs file:

```
axios.post(`/Advising/AddTime/${idValue}/${dayValue}/${startValue}/${endValue}/${timeValue}`)
```

In my Koa (node.js) file:

```
AdvisingRouter.post('/AddTime/:id/:day/:starttime/:endtime/:timeblock', AdvisingController.addTimes, (err) => console.log("routers.js: AdvisingRouter error:", err));
```

And lastly my controller:

```
class AdvisingController {
async addTimes(ctx) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let query = "INSERT INTO AdvisingTimes (id, Day, StartTime, EndTime, TimeBlock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
    console.log('About to run this query.', query);
        dbConnection.query(
            {
                sql: query,
                values: [ctx.params.id, ctx.params.day, ctx.params.starttime, ctx.params.endtime, ctx.params.timeblock]
            }, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                }
            }

        )
    }).catch(err => {
        ctx.body = {
            status: "Failed",
            error: err,
            user: null
        };
    });

}
```

Comment: Checkout the marked answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501185/how-to-post-query-parameters-with-axios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you are using `POST` then you can always send the data as part of the payload

```
axios.post('/Advising/AddTime/', {
  id,
  day,
  starttime,
  endtime,
  timeblock
});
```

Then at the backend you can access the data via `ctx.request.body`

*Note - you would need to include a body parser like [koa-body](https://github.com/dlau/koa-body)*

Answer (score 0):

Helpful function that I use:

```
const insertParams = (url, params) => { // url is string, params is object
  let paramUrl = url;
  const copyParams = Object.assign({}, params);

  Object.keys(copyParams).forEach(key => {
    const currentParam = copyParams[key];
    if (paramUrl.includes(key)) delete copyParams[key];
    paramUrl = paramUrl.replace(`:${key}`, currentParam);
  });
  return paramUrl;
};
```

And for your case simply call insertParams:

```
const url = 'http://your.url.com/';
const params = { id: 'id123', day: 'friday', starttime: new Date(), endtime: new Date(), timeblock: 'timeblock' };

const urlWithParams = insertParams(url, params);
```