# How to send a POST request with variables in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning how to send a POST request to an API with React.

What I'm trying to achieve right now is sending a POST request to an API.
The API will insert the event with something like this (what is this method called?):
`https://api.com/WebService.asmx/insertEvent?event_id=5&desc=<p>HelloWorld</p>&name=testing`

The method that I'm currently using as POST is shown at **POST method** and it returns me with the error `unexpected token '<' in json at position 0` and the result that I get when I `console.log(JSON.stringify(event))` is something like this:

````
{"event_id":"5","desc":"<p>HelloWorld</p>","name":"testing"}```
````

**POST method**

```
const response = await fetch('https://api.com/WebService.asmx/insertEvent', 
         {
             method: 'POST',
             headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
             body: JSON.stringify(event)
        })
```

Edit: I've fixed the above error by encoding the HTML that I need to send. **This is now my latest POST method**, but I'm still facing error 500 for some reason even though it works when I copy and pasted the URL+params from the console.log that has the error shown:

```
const addBulletin = async (event) => {
        console.log(event, '--event')
        const url = 'https://api.com/WebService.asmx/insertEvent';
        axios.post(url, null, { params: {
            title: event.title,
            desc: event.desc,
            image: event.image,
            employee: event.employee,
            entity: event.entity,
            startDate: event.startDate,
            endDate: event.endDate,
            createdBy: event.createdBy
        }})
        .then(response => console.log(response.status))
        .catch(err => console.warn(err));
    };
```

Edit: I've tested the API on a vanilla JS project using .ajax with POST, and it works, so I think the API shouldn't be a problem.

```
var json = $('.insert-form').serialize();

$.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "https://api.com/WebService.asmx/insertEvent",
        data: json,
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Event has been successfully created!");
        },
        error: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
```

Comment: What is your backend framework?

Comment: Are you supposed to be sending the data in query parameters as in the first example? Or are you supposed to be sending a json body?

Comment: use _query-string_ package wich is parse and stringify URL query strings

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551320/11895568

Comment: My backend is MySQL and I'm supposed to be sending the data in query parameters (now I know what it's called). So I'm doing the wrong thing the whole time by sending as a json body.

Comment: The error suggests you might need to look at [URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) the values you're sending in the query parameters.

Comment: It's weird, I've encoded my HTML and it fixed this error but it now has error 500 even though the insert works when I copied and pasted the URL+params from the console error.

Comment: A 500 error (should) indicates an error on the backend. Looks like the POST is fixed, now you should look at the API and why it can't process the request.

Comment: But if directly copy pasting the API URL+params in the browser works, does it still means that the backend has the error?

Comment: A browser performs a GET request when it requests a url. POST typically happens for form events or other client-side JS. I suspect you're supposed to use GET.

Comment: I've tested the API on a vanilla JS project using .ajax with POST, and it works, so I think the API shouldn't be a problem. I've posted the .ajax code in my post above.

Comment: @im_baby I've tried using GET request as a last resort and it worked perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The API you are sending the request to expects a query parameter (data in the URL).
`https://api.com/WebService.asmx/insertEvent?event_id=5&desc=<p>HelloWorld</p>&name=testing`
In this request, we are sending 3 query params: `event_id`, `desc`, and `name`.

To send this kind of request from React, you should not use **request body**. Instead. I advise you to use `axios` to make it easier. It's a very powerful library, better than using `fetch`. It should be done this way:

```
axios.post(`https://api.com/WebService.asmx/insertEvent`, null, { params: {
  event_id: eventId,
  desc
}})
.then(response => response.status)
.catch(err => console.warn(err));
```

This may help: [How to post query parameters with Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501185/how-to-post-query-parameters-with-axios)

Comment: I've tried the method that you've suggested using axios, which it probably worked, but I'm still getting the same error:

A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (desc=&quot;&lt;p&gt;Hello World!&lt;/p&gt; &quot;)

I think this is because I'm trying to save html into the db, which I've tried to escape the html tags by using:

const desc = htmlContent.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');

But it's still showing the same error.

Comment: It's because of the `<p>Hello World</p>` value. The API is sending back that response message. If you are in charge of the API, you can deactivate that message. Although it's not that recommended.

Comment: Okay, now that I've encoded the html code with const desc = encodeURIComponent(htmlContent.replace(/'/g, '\'\'')), the POST request still doesn't work when I send the request through the app (getting error 500), but if I copy the parameters and paste it in the browser manually, it actually successfully inserted the event, so is this error related with the axios post method that I've used? 

**I've posted the POST method that I've used in my original post**