# I'm trying to reset my password in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How can I use this link and get information in vue.js

```
http://localhost:2020/rest-password${token}&id=${data._id}
```

My code is:

```js
const submit = async () => {
    console.log('e');
    try {
        const user = await axios.post(`http://localhost:2020/rest-password${token}&id=${data._id}`,{
            password:password.value
        })
        console.log(user, "sss");
        router.push('/log')

    } catch (e) {
        error.value = e.response
    }
}
```

I tried to get information from Backend, but I think the method is incorrect

When I put the link in Postman I can get it

```
http://localhost:2020/rest-password?token=a3224e69cba1be642b97c2ab7265b607ff9d8052c253cbc221cfee80327d&id=6226fa4a2ff1d47fa2e732d7
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post query parameters with Axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501185/how-to-post-query-parameters-with-axios)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `token` contains only the token value (e.g., `a322⋯327d`), the token is incorrectly appended in the URL string:

```js
const user = await axios.post(`http://localhost:2020/rest-password${token}&id=${data._id}`, {⋯})
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

For example, if `token` were `abcd` and `data._id` were `1234`, the result would be:

```js
const user = await axios.post(`http://localhost:2020/rest-passwordabcd&id=1234`, {⋯})
```

Notice how the `token` value has no delimiters in the string, and just appears in the middle. Specifically, it's missing `token=` before the token value; and the `?` separator before the query parameters.

#### Solution

The string should be formatted like this:

```js
const user = await axios.post(`http://localhost:2020/rest-password?token=${token}&id=${data._id}`, {⋯})
```

As an aside, `rest-password` seems to contain a typo, assuming `rest` should be `reset`.