# Send http request in nodejs to php file running on apache server

Tags: node.js, apache, express, http, xampp

I'm gonna build my own real-time chat room therefore I need to use nodejs as a server.
After reading document in socket.io, I decide to use express.js also.
But before using nodejs, I have been create some html, php, javascript files on xampp.
I want to use those existing file so I can bulid without repeating.

In login part, I want to post data to login.php file to verify therefore I use http request to do this stuff.

apache is running on localhost port default port(80) and 8080
nodejs is running on localhost port 3000

there's my login.js used in router

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const http = require('http');

const options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    path: 'project/php/login.php',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
};

/* GET login page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views', 'login.html'));
});

/* POST login data */
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const authReq = http.request(options, (authRes) => {
        console.log(`Status: ${authRes.statusCode}`);
        console.log(`Headers: ${JSON.stringify(authRes.headers)}`);
        authRes.setEncoding('utf8');
        authRes.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(`Body: ${chunk}`);
        });
        authRes.on('end', () => {
            console.log('No more data in response.');
        });
    });

    authReq.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(`Problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    });
    
    // Write the data to be posted to the request body
    authReq.write(`username=${username}&password=${password}`);
    authReq.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, I got this response

```
POST /login - - ms - -
Status: 400
Headers: {"date":"Mon, 09 Jan 2023 12:48:47 GMT","server":"Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/7.4.29","content-length":"334","connection":"close","content-type":"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"}
Body: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/7.4.29 Server at domain Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Is there something wrong?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You send the request to the default port 80, shouldn't that be 8080?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I open 80 port and 8080 port on apache. I'll edit it in post. Thanks

Comment: try with axios or similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501185/how-to-post-query-parameters-with-axios

Comment: @traynor Thanks for your suggesstion. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who did the foolish like me.

This went wrong because of the 'path' in options
path: **'project/php/login.php'** should be changed to **'/project/php/login.php'**

Everything works.