# Postman returns success, but browser don't

Tags: rest, vue.js, axios

I have a form which related on `v-model`. So, it is default login page. When I try to log in I got unautorized 401, but in Postman I got the token with same credentials.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            output: ''
        };
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            axios.post('api/login', {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password },
                { headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    }
                }).then(response => {
                    this.output = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to stringify your auth object: 
`let authObj = {email: this.email, password: this.password }
axios.post('api/login', JSON.stringify(authObj) ....`

Comment: @Michael same problem

Comment: How are you sending it in postman? Is it in the body? As a header? I think that you are not sending in the same way that is causing this issue

Comment: @Michael sending in the body, with header content type

Comment: see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415439/how-can-i-add-raw-data-body-to-an-axios-request

Comment: @Michael didn't find solution

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
axios.post('api/login/',
    {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }
```